# How can I insert italics in MS Word Find and Replace?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, find-and-replace

I've written a long document and just read the branding guidelines that says the 'e' at the start of a word needs to be italicized, e.g. eBahgum, the e is italics and Bahgum isn't. I've written this loads of times in my doc so want to do a find and replace just to change the e to italics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two Replaces:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to bring up the `Find and Replace` dialog
2. Enter `eBahgum` in the `Find what:` text box
3. Place the cursor in the `Replace with:` text box
4. Click the `More` button
5. Click the `Format` button and select `Font...`
6. Set `Font style:` to `Italic` and click OK [image]
7. Click `Replace All` - all instances of `eBahgum` will now be in italics
8. Change `Find what:` to `Bahgum`
9. Place the cursor in the `Replace with:` text box
10. Click the `Format` button and select `Font...`
11. Set `Font style:` to `Regular` and click OK [image]
12. Click `Replace All` again

All instances of `Bahgum` will now be normal again, leaving the `e` in italics

Comment: Thanks Shevek. Worked like a dream. Found that I didn't even need to go into format. Just clicked ctrl+i in the Replace text box.